# Schengen Area Transit

Tags: schengen, transit, transit-visas, turkish-citizens, cph

I will be flying to Istanbul from Miami and I have a connection flight in Copenhagen. The flight from Miami to Copenhagen and Copenhagen to Istanbul are not operated by the same airline so I have to claim my baggage and check-in again.

The airlines are SAS and Turkish Airlines, but the website I bought them at says I need to self-transfer.

I am traveling on a Turkish passport.

Do I need a Schengen visa/transit visa for that?

Comment: What nationality passport are you traveling with?

Comment: "not operated by the same airline so I have to claim my baggage and check-in again": This isn't necessarily true.  Some airlines can check luggage onto another airline even if you've bought separate tickets.  If the two legs are on the *same* ticket, you almost never have to recheck bags, even if the flights are operated by different airlines.  So if one airline is SAS and the other Turkish (both Star Alliance), the premise of your question may be incorrect.  The question of whether you need a visa depends on your nationality.

Comment: I have a turkish passport.

Comment: Yeah the airlines are SAS and Turkish Airlines, but the website I bought them says I need to self-transfer.

Comment: @lexa If I were you I'd call SAS and possibly also Turkish and ask them.  The website might just be telling everyone they need to self transfer to protect themselves from liability.  If you *do* need to self-transfer, or to pass through immigration control for any reason, you'll need to apply to Denmark for a short-stay visa.  If you *don't* need to pass through immigration control, you won't need a visa.